# Is it possible to disable textbox from selecting part of text through double-click

Tags: winforms, events, textbox

The default behaviour of doubleclicking in a textbox is select part of text. I wanna override it with selecting a word. But I found handling the doubleclick event(or override the OnDoubleClick method) actually do the default behaviour first, then execute my code. Is it possible to disable the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can do this with standard WinForms event handlers (`DoubleClick` and `MouseDoubleClick` don't give you any way to suppress the default behavior), but you can do this by creating a custom `WndProc` and handling the window messages yourself.

In the example below, I override the default [`Control.WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) in the `PreviewTextBox` class I create.  I expose the `PreviewDoubleClick` event through this class which, if handled in client code, can be used to suppress the default double-click behavior by setting `e.Handled = true;`.  In this example, the event is handled in the `OnPreviewDoubleClick` event handler, where you can add your custom code to do react to the double-click however you want.

If you need additional mouse information about the double click, I believe you can get that through the [`Message.LParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.lparam.aspx)/[`Message.WParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message.wparam.aspx) fields in the `WndProc`.

(the code below assumes you have some code behind for the form already setup)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class DoubleClickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool Handled
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class PreviewTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public event EventHandler<DoubleClickEventArgs> PreviewDoubleClick;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if ((m.Msg == WM_DBLCLICK) || (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK))
            {
                var e = new DoubleClickEventArgs();

                if (PreviewDoubleClick != null)
                    PreviewDoubleClick(this, e);

                if (e.Handled)
                    return;
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        const int WM_DBLCLICK = 0xA3;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;
    }

    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _textBox = new PreviewTextBox();
            _textBox.Text = "Test text foo bar";
            _textBox.PreviewDoubleClick += new EventHandler<DoubleClickEventArgs>(OnPreviewDoubleClick);

            Controls.Add(_textBox);
        }

        void OnPreviewDoubleClick(object sender, DoubleClickEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        PreviewTextBox _textBox;
    }
}
```